# Items on listview in listfragment not responding

Tags: android, android-studio

Pls I have a problem. I intend to show a toast when an item on listview is clicked. But the items doesn't show a response that am even clicking them.
Here's the code:

```
package com.ejikedozie.pcsolutions;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ejikedozie.pcsolutions.R;

public class OneFragment extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    public OneFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.Planets, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switch (position){
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Post ur ListFragment class too

Answer (score 1):

You should implements ListView.OnItemClickListener rather than AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

I have just removed the switch case condition and now on all item clicks i got the position.
 Please check it once again

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```